# Output only necessary columns in df

Tags: linux

I am doing df-h / and I need to output only "size" and "use%" columns.
I tried `df -h / |cut -d' ' -f4 -f 5` but it doesn't work. How can I do it?

Comment: Did you try `df -h / | cut -d ' ' -f 4,5`?

Comment: The error message would be worth reporting, too: `cut: only one type of list may be specified`. Reading the man page for `cut` you would see, "Use one, and only one of -b, -c or -f.  Each LIST is made up of  one  range,  or  many       ranges  separated  by  commas."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It did not work because there is multiple spaces in the separators of the df command output.

It could work as

```
$df -h / | tr -s " " | cut -d' ' -f4,5
Avail Use%
1.3G 53%
```

Nevertheless, I prefer to do it as:

```
$df -h / | awk ' { print $4"\t"$5 } '
Avail   Use%
1.3G    53%
```

Note however that for size and use it is the 2nd and 5th field. I also advise to use a tab (\t) as separator,  so it becomes:

```
$df -h / | awk ' { print $2"\t"$5 } '
Size    Use%
2.9G    53%
```

Comment: how to add "-" beetween this results??

Comment: is it "df -h / | awk ' { print $2"-"$5 } '" or df -h / | awk ' { print $2"\t-\t"$5 } ' what you want?

Answer (score 6):

If you have GNU coreutils, you can use the `--output` parameter just:

```
df -h / --output=size,used
```

Comment: While it does not explains what the OP is doing wrong, I do prefer this solution to he getting what he wants from df.

Comment: Nice, `df -h / --output=target,size,used` for OP :)

Comment: It is a pity I cannot upvote an answer more than once. This is very handful.

Answer (score 3):

With a reasonably recent version of `findmnt` as included in the LSB-required *util-linux* package, then

```
findmnt -DoSIZE,USE%
```

does just what it looks like.

"Reasonably recent" includes version 2.27 *(released Dec 2015)*, but not 2.20 *(released Jan 2012)* (which has neither the `-D` flag nor the `SIZE` and `USE%` columns *(because these were introduced with [version 2.22](https://www.kernel.org/pub/linux/utils/util-linux/v2.22/v2.22-ChangeLog) **(released Sep 2012)***).

Comment: @TobySpeight - update.

Comment: @TobySpeight - anyway, you dont need `-D`. the only difference is you'll get listings for virtual filesystems without it. but seriously: update. its *util-linux*. just build the package.

Comment: @TobySpeight - I see it, but v2.20 was released almost 4 years ago. its a required package by the LSB. i just think its weird.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
df -h | awk '{ print $2 " " $5 }'
```